# In Ansible, how to add a block of text at end of a file with a blank line before the marker?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook as shown below:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: update a file
      blockinfile:
        dest: /tmp/test
        block: |
          line 1
          line 2
```

Upon running the playbook, the file `/tmp/test` becomes:

```
a # this is the end line of the original file
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
line 1
line 2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

I would like to add a blank line (newline) before the marker "`# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK`" for visual effect.
What is the easiest way to do it? Preferably within the task, but any idea is welcome. If I redefine the marker, it will affect both the "`BEGIN`" and "`END`" marker.

Comment: I added a [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/80835) to the repo. If you also want this feature then upvote that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file that looks like this:

```
some line
foobar
some other line
```

and you want to add a newline before the pattern "foobar" in this example, the following ansible code will do it for you:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: update a file
      replace:
        dest: /tmp/foobar
        regexp: |
          (?mx)     # "m" lets ^ and $ match next to imbedded \n, x allows white space for readability
          (?<!\n\n) # a Zero-Length Assertion that it does not have an empty line already
          ^         # beginning of the line
          (foobar)  # match "foobar" and save it as \1, it could be "\#\ BEGIN\ ANSIBLE\ MANAGED\ BLOCK" if that is your pattern
          $         # end of line
        replace: "\n\\1" # add a newline before the matched pattern
```

and it is idempotent and it does not add the newline at the end of the file when the pattern is not present.

Comment: I figured it out but it would have been nicer if you explained all the advanced regex symbols and mentioned to replace `foobar` with `# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK[^\n]*`

Comment: I commented on the code and edited the text to make it clear. It is generic in that it adds a new line where it matches. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Use *lineinfile*. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: update a file
      blockinfile:
        dest: /tmp/test
        block: |
          line 1
          line 2
    - name: insert empty line before the marker
      lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/test
        insertbefore: '^# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK$'
        line: ''
```

---

Unfortunately *insertbefore* doesn't work with more blocks. *template* module might be needed if you insist on empty lines among blocks.

Try the playbook below. Unfortunately, EOF doesn't work as expected

```yaml
shell> cat manage-block.yml
- name: "insert {{ my_marker }} in {{ my_dest }}"
  blockinfile:
    dest: "{{ my_dest }}"
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ my_marker }}"
    block: "{{ my_block }}"
- name: "insert empty line before {{ my_marker }}"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ my_dest }}"
    insertbefore: '^# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ my_marker }}'
    line: 'empty line'
  when: ansible_loop.first
- name: "insert empty line after EOF"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ my_dest }}"
    insertafter: EOF
    line: 'empty line'
```

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_blocks:
      /tmp/test:
        - my_marker: block001
          my_block: |
            line 1
            line 2
        - my_marker: block002
          my_block: |
            line 3
            line 4
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: manage-block.yml
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_blocks|dict2items }}"
        - value
      loop_control:
          extended: true
      vars:
        my_dest: "{{ item.0.key }}"
        my_marker: "{{ item.1.my_marker }}"
        my_block: "{{ item.1.my_block }}"
```

Comment: This works 99%. The only issue is it adds the empty line at the end of file when the mark does not exists (e.g. the previous step fails for some reason). The ideal is to add the empty line before the marker only when the marker exists.Why ansible should have this documented behavior (add at the end of file if pattern does not exist), which I have not yet found an use case for.

Comment: IMHO, it's not worth the effort. The module [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) is not maintained by the Ansible Core Team. There are a lot of [open issues with lineinfile](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+lineinfile).

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work with multiple blocks. Only the first one will be separated. It's not clear if this is a bug or not. Only one line will be added by *insertbefore*. See the example and remove the *when* condition to test it.

Comment: See my answer, which works with multiple blocks.

Answer (score 3):

#### For ansible-core version 2.16 and later:

There is a new parameter that has been added to the module `blockinfile`, named [`prepend_newline`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-prepend_newline), which is purposed exactly for this use case, thanks to [@Ionix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9971404/lonix) [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/80835).

So, given the task:

```yaml
- blockinfile:
    path: /tmp/test
    prepend_newline: true
    block: |
      line 1
      line 2
```

This gives the expected:

```
a

# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
line 1
line 2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

And is an idempotent task.

---

#### For ansible-core versions before 2.16:

***Important caveat**: this is sadly not an idempotent task.*

If you are on Ansible 2.5 or above, you could alter the [`marker`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-marker), [`marker_begin`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-marker_begin) and [`marker_end`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-marker_end).

Here is an example task:

```yaml
- blockinfile:
    dest: /tmp/test
    marker: '{mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK'
    marker_begin: '\n# BEGIN' 
    marker_end: '# END'
    block: |
      line 1
      line 2
```

Which will populate the file */tmp/test* with:

```
a
 
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
line 1
line 2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Comment: It works the first time, but it is not idempotent, i.e. the 5 lines (including the new line) get added each time it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done, currently, as one task. But can be done as two:

```yaml
- blockinfile:
    dest: /tmp/test
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK foo bar baz"
    block: |
      line 1
      line 2

- replace:
    dest: /tmp/test
    regexp: "(?<!\n\n)(# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK foo bar baz)"
    replace: '\n\1'           # or '\n\1\n' for padding before and after
```

Unlike the other answers, it is idempotent, and works when there are multiple blocks one after the other. (Detail of the regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76344787/9971404).)

But it would be nice if `blockinfile` **could handle the padding using a new option**.

---

**So, I added a [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/80835) to the repo. If you want this feature then please upvote that issue.**